# Protractor on travis-ci. Unable to connect to host localhost on port 7055 after 45000 ms

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, travis-ci

I'm trying to run protractor (via grunt) on travis-ci.  My tests run successfully when I run them locally, but I keep running into the following error on Travis-ci.  Thanks in advance.

Here is my full project in case any other files are required:
https://github.com/crobby/oshinko-console/tree/travis-integration

$ grunt test-integration --baseUrl=https://${IP}

Running "protractor:default" (protractor) task

Starting selenium standalone server...

[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver

Selenium standalone server started at http://10.10.20.130:40443/wd/hub

ERROR - Unable to start a WebDriver session.

/home/travis/build/crobby/oshinko-console/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js:113

var template = new Error(this.message);

UnknownError: Unable to connect to host localhost on port 7055 after 45000 ms.

My .travis.yml file looks like

```
sudo: required
## use node_js
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "6"
## home folder is /home/travis/build/radanalyticsio/oshinko-console
services:
  - docker
before_install:
## add insecure-registry and restart docker
  - pwd
  - sudo cat /etc/default/docker
  - sudo service docker stop
  - sudo sed -i -e 's/sock/sock --insecure-registry 172.30.0.0\/16/' /etc/default/docker
  - sudo cat /etc/default/docker
  - sudo service docker start
  - sudo service docker status
## chmod needs sudo, so all other commands are with sudo
  - sudo mkdir -p /home/travis/origin
  - sudo chmod -R 766 /home/travis/origin
## download oc 1.5.1 binary
  - sudo wget https://github.com/openshift/origin/releases/download/v1.5.1/openshift-origin-client-tools-v1.5.1-7b451fc-linux-64bit.tar.gz -P /home/travis/origin
  - sudo ls -l /home/travis/origin
  - sudo tar -C /home/travis/origin -xvzf /home/travis/origin/openshift-origin-client-tools-v1.5.1-7b451fc-linux-64bit.tar.gz
  - sudo ls -l /home/travis/origin/openshift-origin-client-tools-v1.5.1-7b451fc-linux-64bit
  - sudo cp /home/travis/origin/openshift-origin-client-tools-v1.5.1-7b451fc-linux-64bit/oc /home/travis/origin
  - sudo chmod -R 766 /home/travis/origin
  - sudo ls -l /home/travis/origin
  - sudo chmod -R +755 /home/travis/origin/*
  - sudo cp /home/travis/origin/oc /bin
  - sudo ls -l /bin
  - oc version
  - export PATH=$PATH:/home/travis/origin/
  - echo $PATH
## below cmd is important to get oc working in ubuntu
  - sudo docker run -v /:/rootfs -ti --rm --entrypoint=/bin/bash --privileged openshift/origin:v1.5.1 -c "mv /rootfs/bin/findmnt /rootfs/bin/findmnt.backup"
  - oc cluster up --host-config-dir=/home/travis/origin
  - sudo ls -l /home/travis/origin
  - oc cluster down
## get the latest release code
  - sudo cp dist/scripts/templates.js /home/travis/origin/master
  - sudo cp dist/scripts/scripts.js /home/travis/origin/master
  - sudo cp dist/styles/oshinko.css /home/travis/origin/master
  - sudo chmod -R 766 /home/travis/origin/master
  - sudo ls -l /home/travis/origin/master
## add changes to master-config.yaml
  - "sudo sed -i -e \"s/extensionScripts: null/extensionScripts:\\n  - templates.js\\n  - scripts.js/\" /home/travis/origin/master/master-config.yaml"
  - "sudo sed -i -e \"s/extensionStylesheets: null/extensionStylesheets:\\n  - oshinko.css/\" /home/travis/origin/master/master-config.yaml"
  - sudo cat /home/travis/origin/master/master-config.yaml
## oc cluster up
  - oc cluster up --host-config-dir=/home/travis/origin --use-existing-config=true
## find IP:PORT of openshift
  - IPSTR=`oc status |grep server`
  - echo $IPSTR
  - IP=${IPSTR##*/}
  - echo ${IP}
install:
  - npm install grunt-cli -g
  - npm install
  - npm install -g protractor
  - node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update
  - node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager status
  - cat node_modules/protractor/config.json
before_script:
  - export DISPLAY=:99.0
  - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
script:
  - echo ${IP}
## integration tests need headless setup
  - grunt test-integration --baseUrl=https://${IP}
notifications:
 email:
   on_success: never
   on_failure: never
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I needed to be using an older firefox to be compatible with the other bits I'm using.

Working .travis.yml is below.

```
sudo: required
## use node_js
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "6"
addons:
  firefox: "46.0"
## home folder is /home/travis/build/radanalyticsio/oshinko-console
services:
  - docker
before_install:
## add insecure-registry and restart docker
  - pwd
  - sudo cat /etc/default/docker
  - sudo service docker stop
  - sudo sed -i -e 's/sock/sock --insecure-registry 172.30.0.0\/16/' /etc/default/docker
  - sudo cat /etc/default/docker
  - sudo service docker start
  - sudo service docker status
## chmod needs sudo, so all other commands are with sudo
  - sudo mkdir -p /home/travis/origin
  - sudo chmod -R 766 /home/travis/origin
## download oc 1.5.1 binary
  - sudo wget https://github.com/openshift/origin/releases/download/v1.5.1/openshift-origin-client-tools-v1.5.1-7b451fc-linux-64bit.tar.gz -P /home/travis/origin
  - sudo ls -l /home/travis/origin
  - sudo tar -C /home/travis/origin -xvzf /home/travis/origin/openshift-origin-client-tools-v1.5.1-7b451fc-linux-64bit.tar.gz
  - sudo ls -l /home/travis/origin/openshift-origin-client-tools-v1.5.1-7b451fc-linux-64bit
  - sudo cp /home/travis/origin/openshift-origin-client-tools-v1.5.1-7b451fc-linux-64bit/oc /home/travis/origin
  - sudo chmod -R 766 /home/travis/origin
  - sudo ls -l /home/travis/origin
  - sudo chmod -R +755 /home/travis/origin/*
  - sudo cp /home/travis/origin/oc /bin
  - sudo ls -l /bin
  - oc version
  - export PATH=$PATH:/home/travis/origin/
  - echo $PATH
## below cmd is important to get oc working in ubuntu
  - sudo docker run -v /:/rootfs -ti --rm --entrypoint=/bin/bash --privileged openshift/origin:v1.5.1 -c "mv /rootfs/bin/findmnt /rootfs/bin/findmnt.backup"
  - oc cluster up --host-config-dir=/home/travis/origin
  - sudo ls -l /home/travis/origin
  - oc cluster down
## get the latest release code
  - sudo cp dist/scripts/templates.js /home/travis/origin/master
  - sudo cp dist/scripts/scripts.js /home/travis/origin/master
  - sudo cp dist/styles/oshinko.css /home/travis/origin/master
  - sudo chmod -R 766 /home/travis/origin/master
  - sudo ls -l /home/travis/origin/master
## add changes to master-config.yaml
  - "sudo sed -i -e \"s/extensionScripts: null/extensionScripts:\\n  - templates.js\\n  - scripts.js/\" /home/travis/origin/master/master-config.yaml"
  - "sudo sed -i -e \"s/extensionStylesheets: null/extensionStylesheets:\\n  - oshinko.css/\" /home/travis/origin/master/master-config.yaml"
  - sudo cat /home/travis/origin/master/master-config.yaml
## oc cluster up
  - oc cluster up --host-config-dir=/home/travis/origin --use-existing-config=true
## find IP:PORT of openshift
  - IPSTR=`oc status |grep server`
  - echo $IPSTR
  - IP=${IPSTR##*/}
  - echo ${IP}
install:
  - npm install grunt-cli -g
  - npm install
  - npm install grunt-protractor-runner@1.2.1
  - ./node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/scripts/webdriver-manager-update
before_script:
  - export DISPLAY=:99.0
  - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
script:
  - echo ${IP}
## integration tests need headless setup
  - grunt test-integration --baseUrl=https://${IP}
notifications:
 email:
   on_success: never
   on_failure: never
```